# How do I initialize a std::unique_ptr with a deleter in a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to wrap a C library raw pointer in a std::unique_ptr and use the constructor with the Deleter to call the library free function. I have to do some setup in the constructor in order to setup the raw pointer so I can't construct the unique_ptr in the initializer list.

.h

```
class Resampler {

public:
    Resampler(unsigned int baseSamplerate, unsigned int channels);
  
private:
    std::unique_ptr<SwrContext, decltype(&swr_free)> context{nullptr, nullptr};
};
```

.cpp

```
Resampler::Resampler(unsigned int baseSamplerate, unsigned int channels) : baseSamplerate(baseSamplerate), ratio(1.0), channels(channels) {

    int64_t channelLayout;
     ..

    SwrContext *ctx = swr_alloc_set_opts(nullptr,
                                         channelLayout,
                                         AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP,
                                         baseSamplerate,
                                         channelLayout,
                                         AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP,
                                         baseSamplerate,
                                         0,
                                         nullptr);

    context = std::unique_ptr<SwrContext, decltype(&swr_free)>(ctx, &swr_free);
    setRatio(1.0);
}
```

This doesn't produce an error in the IDE but the compiler complains:

> ```
> > error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'SwrContext **' with an
> > lvalue of type 'std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<SwrContext, void
> > (*)(SwrContext **)>::pointer' (aka 'SwrContext *')
> ```

```
std::unique_ptr<SwrContext, decltype(&swr_free)> context{ nullptr };
```

and

```
std::unique_ptr<SwrContext, decltype(&swr_free)> context{};
```

are not valid constructors, and

```
std::unique_ptr<SwrContext, decltype(&swr_free)> context;
```

produces

> error: constructor for 'Resampler' must explicitly initialize the
> member 'context' which does not have a default constructor

so is there a way to do this or should I just make context a raw pointer and manually manage?

Answer (score 2):

The deleter of a `std::unique_ptr<T>` has to be a callable object in this case. Try using a *functor* like this:

```
struct swr_deleter
{
    void operator()(SwrContext* context)
    {
        if (context != nullptr)
        {
            swr_free(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your `std::unique_ptr` will look like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<SwrContext, swr_deleter> context;
```

Comment: This allowed me to get it working. I think the issue is because sw_free takes a ** and not a *. So in my case I needed to do `swr_free(&context);'. I think that may be my original way didn't work.

Comment: "*the deleter of a `std::unique_ptr<T>` has to be a callable object*" - standalone functions are also valid as deleters. Just not in this particular case, because the signature of `swr_free()` is not compatible with the requirement of a deleter, since it takes a `SwrContext**` instead of a `SwrContext*`. Using a functor can work around that